# Redis Commander - How to delete keys from Redis DB based on date created?

Tags: redis

I want to delete keys created between 2 particular timestamps - For example between 2pm, 2nd May and 3pm, 2nd May.

I am using [Redis commander](https://github.com/joeferner/redis-commander) and couldn't find any command for this in their documentation